# Mysql: How can I structure a table to hold usernames of various social networks?

Tags: mysql

I want to store social network usernames for each of my site's users. How can I structure this table to hold the names of the social network sites along with the username for the given site?

```
Users
    id
    first_name
    last_name

Profiles
    fk_users_id
    country

social_networks
    id
    name

social_accounts ?
    fk_users_id ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create  a new relation table.And create the social_accounts keep the relation table_id as FK.

```
socialnetworks_user_relation
----------------------------
relation_id    
user_id (FK_user_id)
network_id(FK_socialnetwork_id)



social_accounts
-----------------    
relation_id(FK_socialnetworks_user_relation)
account_uname
account_pass
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. I'm sure that will work. I'm just trying to wrap my ahead around selecting a user first_name plus social_network.name and different social accounts sites along with their usernames. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: any suggestion @JDeveloper would be hugely appreciated